# GitHub Repository Fork in Enterprise

Tags: git, github

I will try to explain my Question as clearly as possible.

Okay, I am working in a big enterprise financial company and one of the team has worked on some project for their stuffs and has github repository.

Now, We (another two new team) want to utilize their work for our need and going to use their repository.

We have 10 people who will be working in my office for this( which equals two teams).

I has forked their repository has we don't have direct push access, to theirs.
I was thinking other 9 people can use this forked repository and create individual branches in it work on their part, push the changes to their branches, then we all 10 can merge everything to our masters of forked branch and then we as a team can create a major pull request to original project (from which we forked). so, we don't send them individual pull requests( when we all together will be working on one feature or two)

Now, Question is, is this a right way? to work or should we create individual forks which i think will be hard to manage among ourself even.

Please ask if this scenarios is not very clear, not sure if I have explained it best. 
Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, Question is, is this a right way?

This is the exact way you should work, you got it all correctly and you have a full understanding on how to work with git.

Since you don't have permissions to contribute back to the original repository you need to use pull request to do so, just like you understood you should do.

Comment: Thanks @CodeWizard. Just many people in team was not agreeing on it and was in favor of having various forked repo, so I was thinking to ask experts here. Thank you! I will put my point again.

Comment: You just have to think of a good way not to have too many forks in order to be bale to manage it right.

Comment: Agree! that was the reason I was thinking one fork and multiple branches in it because we are going to work together on one or two features. Yeah what you are saying totally make sense.

Comment: Again, you understand correctly what is fork and how to work with it.

Comment: One more question I had, will other people will be able to create branch in my forked repo? because my forked repo will be something like : MyUsername/app   right? so do  I need to give any access so they can create branch in mine forked one or should they need to refork my forked repo?

Comment: yep. once you add contributors to your repo you can control which permission they will have and you can give it per branch as well. If you add them as contributors they will need to re-fork your project since they will have permissions to push

Comment: Thanks. I think branch level permission will be good that way , i don;t have to see all 9 fork pull request to merge in my forked repo and then have a pull request to original one. with branch everyone can have push to their branch and then we all can come up with plan how to merge in masters of our forked repo. Thanks a ton!